# How to access client socket id from the http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, socket.io

Recently I've stumbled upon an interesting problem.

The goal was to create a communication between a browser client and my expressJs server via web sockets to quickly show changes made on the another client. Also I'm using a standard http connection to communicate with my database.

The problem is that I need to generate an individual link for every user (based on their cookie I've created) but on the server only the last one is valid.
So every person displaying invalid link should see something like `Please refresh the page`.
To achieve that I've emitted event `linkExpired` globally which marked sender's link as expired as well.

I can't access a client socket (which would solve my problem) because I don't want to store them after establishing connection (as was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44138851/8486695) for example). In my opinion it isn't an elegant solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should state your question and problem in your post, and then answer your own post and mark your answer as a valid one. Otherwise it is not clear, that your question has already an answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I don't know why I didn't think of that :D
I'll change it right away. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I've come up with a different approach.
Maybe creating a cookie storing id of the client socket after establishing connection would be sufficient. So I did that... And I've realised that `socket.io` already have a cookie containing a socket id.

The only thing to do was to use `cookie-parser` with express:

```js
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
require('express')().use(cookieParser());
```

After that I had an access to all the cookies passed to all http requests which allowed me to filter sockets based on the id and avoid sending an event to the sender.

```js
const io = require("socket.io").io;
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach((_socketId) => {
  if (req.cookies.io !== _socketId) {
    io.to(_socketId).emit('linkExpired');
  }
});
```

Please pay attention to the fragment where I used a `req.cookies.io` as an id of the socket. I've noticed that `socket.io` is using cookie named `io` to store current id of the client socket.

And on the client side I could achieve showing banner about expiration as follows:

```js
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const io = socketIOClient(process.env.REACT_APP_URL);
io.on('linkExpired', () => {
  setLink('Refresh the page');
});
```

Also I had to remember to pass options to the `fetch` method to send cookies:

```js
fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL}/api/main`, {
  credentials: 'include'
});
```

I've spend too much time with this so I hope somebody would benefit from this explanation.